# How is this function dealing into 2 lists?

Tags: haskell, recursion, haskell-platform

The purpose of this self created function is to take in a list, and output 2 lists, they are to ne inserted into the lists alternating. SO [4,5,1,6,7,8] will be dealt into 2 lists like ([4,1,7],[5,6,8])

```
deal :: [a] -> ([a],[a])
deal [] = ([],[])
deal [x] = ([x],[])
deal (x:xs) = let (ys,zs) = deal xs
              in (x:zs, ys)
```

this is the function. Im not understanding what is happening with let (ys,zs) = deal xs, i know its basically creating a placeholder for 2 lists but can someone walk me through the recursion thats taking place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition,

```
deal [8] = ([8], [])
```

Now:

```
deal [7,8]
= deal (7:[8])
= let (ys,zs) = deal [8]
  in (7:zs, ys)
-- from the recursion we discover ys=[8], zs=[]
= (7:[], [8])
= ([7], [8])
```

Again:

```
deal [6,7,8]
= deal (6:[7,8])
= let (ys,zs) = deal [7,8]
  in (6:zs, ys)
-- from the recursion we discover ys=[7], zs=[8]
= (6:[8], [7])
= ([6,8], [7])
```

And so on. Every time we recurse, we swap the previous result pair and  prepend an item to the first component. Because of the swaps, it's like adding an element to the first component, then to the second one, then again to the first, and so on, alternating. This splits the list in half, roughly speaking.

Comment: Ok that cleared some things up, however im still confused on how in the 2nd example, how does the recursion return ys = [7], and zs = [8], how would it work for a longer list, thats doing recursion on a list that has more than 2 elements left in the list.

Comment: @gdubbwilliamson In the previous example we saw that `deal [7,8] = ... = ([7], [8])`, so letting `(ys,zs)=deal [7,8]` is like letting `(ys,zs)=([7],[8])`. You can as an exercise try computing `deal [1,6,7,8]`: on the recursion step you can exploit that `deal [6,7,8] = ([6,8],[7])`, as we saw in the last example above.

Comment: ahh okay that makes perfect sense now, is this whats called pattern matching in haskell? it recognizes the pattern on how its being added to the ys, zs then continues it?

Comment: @gdubbwilliamson `let (a,b) = some expression in ...`  is indeed a form of pattern matching. It defines `a` and `b` as the two components of the pair resulting from evaluating the expression (in your case, the recursive function call).